# What should I do if I got a good comment to edit my answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments

What should I do if I got a good comment from another to edit my answer?

It seems hard to choice for me, because writing is different from speaking, and sometime overhead in post/comment or a notice message when using `@user_x` may bother one's attention.

1. Just edit my answer accordingly and upvote the comment.
2. Edit with p/s in my answer that edited thank the user's comment.
3. Edit my answer and add another comment to thank the user.
4. Other.

Comment: This has been asked before, but I can't really find it. Don't mention usernames in your answer, because that distracts from the actual answer.

Comment: If you must give attribution (which is different from thanking someone, that you shouldn't do), do so in a foot note. It's the least relevant information to provide after all.

Answer (score 16):

When you get a comment on how to improve your answer, then you should:

1. Edit your answer

   1.1 If the contribution was significant (e.g., more than "< should be >", ...) then you can (but are not obliged to) add some text stating "As suggested by xyz" or "(idea from xyz)". Make sure that the attribution does not distract from the answer content itself.
2. Flag the comment as No longer needed

Comment: Don’t use the @ adornment. There are no pings in posts.

Comment: A tactic I often use is to thank people in my edit summaries. That way the thanks don't clutter the post but there's still a permanent record of the other user's contribution. If you're engaged and organised enough to do so, you can also post a comment @-replying to the user to thank them, then swing by a few days later once they've probably seen your reply and flag for the mods to nuke the entire comment thread.

Comment: How do you flag a comment as not needed?

Comment: Click the flag icon in front of a comment that isn't yours

Comment: It's kinda funny how the thing that this question is about happened in it's answers :D

Comment: Should we add hyperlink of user profile in attribution since name is not a unique way to identify user after comment deletion?

Comment: @AbdulRauf -- I add a hyperlink to the user profile.  This means the acknowledgement can still be followed even if the user changes their username.  But this is something that most users do not know how to do, so I do not expect others to do so.

Answer (score 14):

Option 1.

Edit your post (no "PS", no "Edit" header, just edit your post so it reads naturally and incorporates the improvements as you see fit).

Upvote the comment, and **optionally comment ping the other user to let them know you've incorporated their suggestion**, so they can delete their comment if they wish.

Generally, I **wouldn't** mention the origin of the suggestion within the post. Ideally that comment *will be deleted*, so referring to a now deleted comment seems rather distracting and impractical. You can always use the edit summary to leave trace of the attribution, if you feel inclined. This way at least it won't clutter the post (although in fairness this kind of attribution won't be read by many users).

After incorporating the changes, flagging as NLN is logically a good choice, but sometimes it's not obvious for mods that the post was edited to incorporate the suggestion. There could be some difference between the suggestion and the actual edit, or other subtleties that require close inspection.

In any case, **it necessitates the mod opening the post and compare it with the comment** to see if the flag is really appropriate or the flagger is trying to get rid of a valid comment.

You could "custom flag" to explain this to the mod. I thought this would be a bit of overkill for these cases, but apparently the mods like it this way. A good comment explaining that the comment is obsolete obviates the need to read to context and is more likely to get approved.

Personally, I'd leave it to the commenting user in most cases. Once the post is improved the comment can still have a use if another user wants to add a counterpoint. In many cases, users commenting to improve a post are vigilant enough to remove these comments if they feel they served their purpose.

Comment: I mostly like this answer, but "[g]enerally, I wouldn't mention the origin of the suggestion" feels off. Adequate attribution should trump noise reduction, and at any rate end notes or edit summaries (as Gimby and Mark Amery suggest) can be used if one finds it awkward to integrate it to the main body of the answer.

Comment: custom flag is a good idea (we talked about that with Cody yesterday). That saves time for the moderators when they process the flag, as they don't have to open the context.

Comment: I was hesitant to encourage custom flags since I thought they were somewhat more time-consuming for you mods, @Jean. But it's great to know it's a diamond-approved way.

Comment: @duplode Edit summaries sound like a good idea as they don't clutter the post. Foot notes however sound like a very bad idea because attribution doesn't help the reader in any way.

Comment: *Don’t use custom flags* for that. The point of “No longer needed” is that it does *not* need moderators to step in. When enough people see the comment, realizing that the edit has been done, will flag for “No longer needed”, the comment will be removed automatically. Calling for moderator’s attention here, is the wrong choice. By the way, Option 3, making the edit and making a “thank you” comment `@` the other commenter is also not a bad choice. When I get such a “thank you” comment, I’ll remove my original comment and flag the “thank you” comment as “No longer needed” which will remove it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Really? You suggest to use custom flags instead of “No longer needed”, when “No longer needed” is actually appropriate? Why do we have automated flag handling, when you wish to handle all of them manually?

Comment: "The point of “No longer needed” is that it does not need moderators to step in. When enough people see the comment, realizing that the edit has been done, will flag for “No longer needed”, the comment will be removed automatically": I wasn't even aware of that. And even if I was, well, how many people will actually dare to flag a good comment as no longer needed? You should see the amount of flags to process & the work to process them properly to understand.

Comment: there should be a different "noise" comment different from "no longer needed". No longer needed means that it was _useful_ at some point. Unlike "thanks this is the best answer" comment. So NLN flags could allow custom comments.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, someone at SO decided, that differentiating between comments that were once useful and unnecessary comments is not necessary and they all have one flag, “No longer needed”, which might be ok, technically, as they are handled the same way, eventually; the comment will be removed if enough users flag it (except for the “secret trigger words” which will accelerate the process, though, it’s not such a secret that “thank you” seems to be among the list).

Comment: You should see how many pure noise comments we're deleting every day though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre generally, if the comment is older than the post’s last edit, you might assume that a “No longer needed” flag is justified. A custom flag where the user says that the comment’s content has been edited into the post, is not better in that regard. In either case, you are just trusting the user who flagged the comment.

Comment: yed, but for that you have to open the post/check dates/etc... Reading the comment isn't enough. Get 50 comments like that and waste 1 hour. Well, not a biggie anyway. NLN comments aren't the worst issue in moderation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just handle “No longer needed” flags after all others. As said, they are handled automatically if more people flag the comment, further, people like me are going through their comments from time to time, to clean up. So giving the community more time can work in your favor. In contrast, custom flags must be handled by you anyway.

Comment: that method has advantages, but the drawback is that NLN comments rot in moderator queue much longer.

Comment: @DavidMulder "Foot notes however sound like a very bad idea because attribution doesn't help the reader in any way" -- (1) The point of attribution isn't directly helping the reader; it should be provided for its own sake. (2) Consider a slightly different situation from the one described in this question, in which the original revision of an answer incorporates substantial contributions from comments to the question. In such a case, using edit summaries to provide attribution will not be a viable option.

Comment: @duplode To me, attribution is not necessary. When I comment, to suggest an improvement, I’m suggesting to the author to make it their own. I could edit the post instead, then, everyone could see, I made the edit. However, I rather want the original author to understand my point and once the understanding is there, the author is fully right in incorporating this new understanding into their post as their own edit. Some authors still decide to attribute things to me, that’s fine, but it’s not necessary. I agree that edit summaries are indeed not a viable option. A post should stand on its own.

Comment: @Holger In the general case, I don't think we can assume the difference of intent between edits and comments that you suggest. In my experience, the most substantive and transformative suggestions to answers tend to be done through comments, as the authors of such suggestions usually aren't sure about how to best incorporate them to the existing text of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me the history of posts can be interesting and helpful, the same way as e.g. knowing the history of C and C++ provides better insight in and understanding of C++ as it is today. History provides context; the history of a collective thought process provides insight into how the author arrived at a certain conclusion. That's helpful for one's own thought process which may initially follow the same lines, so that the same corrective arguments are helpful.

Of course there are comments and comments. A simple factual error or typo should be silently corrected; it's insights which are more complex and less obvious for which I appreciate history.